# Dirac Notation: How $|f\rangle= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|\phi_j\rangle\langle\phi_j|f\rangle$?

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics

In a text, it has been written that a function is  $|f\rangle= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j|\phi_j\rangle$,  how one can write that -

$  |f\rangle= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|\phi_j\rangle\langle\phi_j|f\rangle$,

and

$  |f\rangle= (\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|\phi_j\rangle\langle\phi_j|)|f\rangle$? plz show the derivation.

The text is given below-

[image]

Comment: Note that the $a_j$ for orthonormal basis is just $<\phi_j|f>$. So you have extra $a_j$ in your formula

Comment: I think it's sad that the text explains that you put together a bra and a ket, but fails to mention that the result is a bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $a_j=\langle \phi_j\mid f\rangle$. This immediately gives
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j|\phi_j\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle \phi_j\mid f\rangle |\phi_j\rangle
$$
(You have an extra $a_j$ on the right-hand side here; that's a typo and not present in your image.)

Now consider the fact that $\langle \phi_j\mid f\rangle$ is just a number, so it commutes with $|\phi_j\rangle$, giving us
$$
=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|\phi_j\rangle\langle \phi_j\mid f\rangle
$$
Finally, Dirac notation multiplication is associative and distributive, so we may group the middle $\langle \phi_j|$ with the left-hand $|\phi_j\rangle$ rather than the right-hand $|f\rangle$, and move the $|f\rangle$ outside the sum.

Comment: You wrote $a_j=\langle \phi_j\mid f\rangle$, how you got that? 

Suppose a Hilbert space $H$ has a basis $\{ \phi_1, \phi_2 \cdots \}$ such that $\langle \phi_i|\phi_j \rangle= 0$ for $i \neq j$.
Then, let $f \in H$ have the expansion $f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \phi_n$, by using the scalar product, we get, $a_n={\langle \phi_n|f \rangle}{\langle \phi_n|\phi_n \rangle}$, but how you got   $a_j=\langle \phi_j\mid f\rangle$?

Comment: @Andrew Well, $|f\rangle$ must have _some_ expansion $$|f\rangle = \sum_j a_j|\phi_j\rangle$$, right? Now multiply on both sides from the left with $\langle\phi_k|$, and we get$$\langle \phi_k\mid f\rangle =\sum_j a_j\langle \phi_k\mid\phi_j\rangle=0+0+0+\cdots +0+ a_k+0+\cdots$$ which after removing all the zeroes is the identity you're asking about.

Comment: Did u see the other answer?  I don't get that answer, could u comment on that?

Comment: @Andrew As far as I can tell, that are mostly being _very careful_ about multiplying in $\langle \phi_k|$ in the infinite sum, and the "removing all the infinitely many zeroes" part. And to be honest, maybe one technically ought to be that careful. But mathematical rigor isn't the most important part of quantum mechanics. Generally, one just assumes that things work out nicely, and it almost always does.

Answer (score 1):

The equality in the title is wrong. If the sequence $|\phi_i\rangle$ forms a complete orthonormal system, we have that every vector is expressable in the following way:
$$|f\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}f_i|\phi_i\rangle$$
Where the equality means convergence in norm induced by the inner product. To get the coefficients, we can do the following:
define $|s_n\rangle$ as
$$|s_n\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i |\phi_i\rangle$$
Then we have that
$$\langle \phi_j| s_n \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i \langle \phi_j|\phi_i\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i \delta_{ij}$$
Taking the limit as $n\to +\infty$, we get that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\langle\phi_j|s_n\rangle=\langle\phi_j|f\rangle$$
While
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i \delta_{ij}=f_j$$
Which means that
$$f_j=\langle\phi_j|f\rangle$$
And finaly
$$|f\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\langle\phi_i|f\rangle |\phi_i\rangle$$
Usually the diad $|\phi_i\rangle \langle \phi_i|$ is defined as
$$\big(|\phi_i\rangle \langle \phi_i|\big) |v\rangle= \big(\langle\phi_i|v\rangle\big)|\phi_i\rangle \quad \forall v \in H$$
And this allows us to rewrite the sum as you wanted:
$$|f\rangle = \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}|\phi_i\rangle\langle\phi_i|\bigg)|f\rangle $$